# How can I implement snap carousel in Vertical direction?

Tags: javascript, react-native-snap-carousel

I need to create List but using snap carousel component. But I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a prop to `carousel` as `vertical`.
You can refer https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel
For using the vertical props find it here https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/src/carousel/Carousel.js

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical prop for achieving in vertical direction.However you must specify itemHeight and sliderHeight while using vertical prop.